# Remove white space around image in .Net MAUI AspectFit

Tags: image, xaml, maui

I have a simple VerticalLayout in .Net MAUI. I'm attempting to put an image between two labels. However, a lot of white space is added before and after the image.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Helpers" x:Class="MyApp.Views.OrgDash.VolunteerPage" Title="MyTitle">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0" RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,10,10,0">
                <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="verticalLayout">
                    <Label x:Name="nameLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label x:Name="emailLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <local:HyperlinkSpan x:Name="emailSpan" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label x:Name="ageLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label x:Name="drivingLicenseLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label x:Name="commentsLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Image x:Name="avatarImage" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                    <Label x:Name="contactInformationLabel" Text="Contact Information" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label x:Name="phoneLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <local:HyperlinkSpan x:Name="phoneSpan" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label x:Name="addressLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label x:Name="emergencyInformationLabel" Text="Emergency Contact Information" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label x:Name="emergencyNameLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label x:Name="emergencyRelationshipLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label x:Name="emergencyEmailLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <local:HyperlinkSpan x:Name="emergencyEmailSpan" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label x:Name="emergencyPhoneLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <local:HyperlinkSpan x:Name="emergencyPhoneSpan" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label x:Name="UseaNumberHeaderLabel" Text="USEA Number" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label x:Name="UseaNumberLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,15,10,15">
                <Button x:Name="emailButton" Text="Email" Clicked="OnEmailClicked" CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The AspectFit option only tries to fit the image into the given bounds while maintaining the original aspect ratio. It does not resize the control itself to the bounds of the image. You'll need to specify a `HeightRequest` for the Image. For XF I developed a simple component [epj.AscpectView.Forms](https://github.com/ewerspej/epj.AspectView.Forms) that takes care of this provided you know the required aspect ratio of the content. However it's not working for MAUI yet, because the layout engine works a little differently now.

Comment: In XF, I just had <Image x:Name="avatarImage" HorizontalOptions="Center" /> and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in .Net MAUI 8.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14139